# OSM get duration and directions from route A to B in Python

Tags: openstreetmap, geopy, overpass-api

I am new to working with Maps and search algorithms. Currently I am using `geopy` package to get distances from `Nominatim`

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from geopy.distance import vincenty

nom = Nominatim()
chicago = nom.geocode("chicago")
dallas = nom.geocode("dallas")
chicago_gps = (chicago.latitude, chicago.longitude)
dallas_gps = (dallas.latitude, dallas.longitude)
distance = vincenty(chicago_gps, dallas_gps).km
print('Distance in kms: {}'.format(distance))
print(chicago.raw)
```

**output**

```
Distance in kms: 1294.7623005649557
{'lat': '41.8755546', 'osm_id': '122604', 'boundingbox': ['41.643919', '42.0230219', '-87.940101', '-87.5239841'], 'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright', 'lon': '-87.6244212', 'place_id': '178038280', 'class': 'place', 'icon': 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/images/mapicons/poi_place_city.p.20.png', 'osm_type': 'relation', 'importance': 0.29566190262222, 'display_name': 'Chicago, Cook County, Illinois, United States of America', 'type': 'city'}
```

So for each place I can calculate the distance. Now there are few questions

1. Is it an airline distance ? Also does OSM provide duration of the journey like Google does ?
2. How can I get directions if I want to go from "Chicago" to "Dallas" like google ? Is there way we get the routing directly from OSM apart from using APIs [MapQuest](https://www.mapquest.com/) etc ?
3. How can we implement traffic layers in our model ? I need some good resources in that and if there are any python implementations of that it would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it an airline distance?

Yes, see the [geopy documentation on distance calculation](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#module-geopy.distance). geopy doesn't support real routing at the moment.

> Also does OSM provide duration of the journey like Google does?

Yes it does if you use a real router. Take a look at [OSM-based online routers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers). Several of them, such as GraphHopper and OSRM, provide turn-by-turn instructions.

> How can I get directions if I want to go from "Chicago" to "Dallas" like google ? Is there way we get the routing directly from OSM apart from using APIs MapQuest etc?

See my previous answer. Use the API of one of the many online routers. Alternatively run your own routing instance. Many of these routers are open source and can be installed locally.

> How can we implement traffic layers in our model ? I need some good resources in that and if there are any python implementations of that it would be great.

Can't help you with that. I would start by taking a look at http://opentraffic.io/ and https://github.com/graphhopper/open-traffic-collection.

Comment: Thank you or the step by step answer.

Comment: So by creating instance you mean downloading the all the data from OSM to my own server, setup the server and moving on from there ?

Comment: Yes. Either for the full planet or for a specific area/country you are interested in.